# BeautifulSoup's find_all( ) method: finding exact occurrance?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup for web scraping.

For example, I have the following html code to scrape:

```
<ul>
    <li class="product-item">Product A</li>
    <li class="product-item child-product">Product B</li>
    <li class="product-item child-product">Product C</li>
    <li class="product-item child-product">Product D</li>
</ul>
```

Using BeautifulSoup, I want to ONLY find the products with the attribute class="product-item" (only Product A), not the 'child-products'

If I do the following:

```
product_list = soup.find_all('li', {'class': 'product-item'})
```

the result includes ALL the products A,B,C, and D.

I've read another [post about the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match), and I followed the suggested and did the following, but the result is the same... It returns all the products.

```
product_list = soup.findAll(attrs={'class': re.compile(r"^product-item$")})
```

What should I do to find products whose class EXACTLY matches 'product-item'??

Comment: I don't think you can do what you want with BeautifulSoup; filter out any tags with more classes instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. What should make it include `Product B` but not `Product C` which is attributed the same?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Sorry! I edited the question. It should return only product A, not B/C/D

Comment: Doesn't just plain `soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'product-item'})` work? If not, which version are you using? You're using `find_all` and `findAll` interchangeably in the question :)

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: BeautifulSoup (correctly) classifies the `class` attribute as a list attribute; it'll match any one of the classes listed. So your `findAll()` call will find all elements with *at least* the `product-item` class.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: In BeautifulSoup 4, `findAll()` is a (deprecated) alias for `find_all()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hm, then the behaviour changed from BS3, there I only seem to get a match on ProductA with my matcher, to get B,C,D I need `soup.findAll(attrs={'class': 'product-item child-product'})`. Ie exact match, not class wise.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson: If you use a space in the `class` attribute match, it still works like that (match against the whole attribute instead of using a list membership test), but that is not helping the OP here.

Comment: But this is a duplicate of the other post. Don't repost a question you didn't get a satisfactory answer on, please.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well, if there is a question that other people might have ask in the future, but does not have the right answer, then I don't get why reposting the question is a problem. Unless it has been established that the question is unsolvable, someone should ask the same question so that more people can view it.

Comment: @user2436815: you should instead [draw attention to the question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions). Do **not** repost, that just clutters up the site. I gave you an answer there.

Comment: @user2436815: besides, you only waited 12 or 13 hours before reposting this. You could have been a little more patient.

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% BeautifulSoup solution, but you can do what you need using bs4+a regular comprehension;

```py
>>> [e for e in soup.find_all('li', class_='product-item') if len(e['class'])==1]

[<li class="product-item">Product A</li>]
```