# How to use Beautiful4 to filter multi class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
    <div class="aa bb"></div>
    <div class="aa ccc"></div>
    <div class="aa"></div>
"""


def find(aclass):
    print(aclass)
    return aclass != "bb"

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

div = soup.find_all('div', attrs={'class': find})

print(div)
```

I just want class='aa', not 'aa bb' or any others.
Please help me!
Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use a simple [CSS selector](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
soup.select("div[class=aa]")
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html = """
...     <div class="aa bb"></div>
...     <div class="aa ccc"></div>
...     <div class="aa"></div>
... """
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> 
>>> for elm in soup.select("div[class=aa]"):
...     print(str(elm))
... 
<div class="aa"></div>
```

Comment: this one also can solve my problem, but I can't vote your answer...feel sorry for that...thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Here was an answer
[BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): finding exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match)

This will give you only the tag with 'aa' class.

```
div = soup.find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['aa'])
```