# BeautifulSoup partial div class matching

Tags: github, beautifulsoup

I need to fetch milestone information from Github by scraping.
The milestone information is embedded in 2 types of div classes:
`table-list-item milestone notdue` and `table-list-item milestone`.

How can I retrieve the information contained in both classes?

I have: 
`milestones = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'table-list-item milestone'})`
but this line returns empty list for `table-list-item milestone notdue`

Right now I am doing the following (ugly hack):

```
milestones = soup.find_all('div', {'class':'table-list-item milestone'})
milestones.extend(soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'table-list-item milestone notdue'}))
```

Is there any elegant solution for this?

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match) question, BeautifulSoup is supposed to return all matching ones. My issue is exactly opposite!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'milestone'})
```

or use CSS selector:

```
soup.select('.milestone')
```

in bs4, `class` is Multi-valued attributes:

it's store in list:`[table-list-item, milestone, notdue] and [table-list-item, milestone]`

what you need to do is find the shared value,like `milestone`

Comment: i am wondering, in that case, how `[table-list-item, milestone]` being common was not true for the other list. using `milestone` only helps! thanks