# Beautiful soup, exact match when using "findAll()"

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup

im scraping a site using python (3.5), selenium (3.6) and beautiful soup (4.6).
The code im using to find a certain html tag is the following:

```
descContainer=descContainers[0].findAll("div", {"class":"userHtml"})
```

unfortunately i'm not only finding my target div which is:

```
<div class="userHtml">
```

but also the following div whose class name partly consists of the class name of interest:

```
<div class="cept-threadUpdate-html toggleSect-hide--collapsed userHtml space--b-2 space--h-2" data-lightbox-xhr="{"name":"thread_updates"}" data-handler="lightbox-xhr emoticon-preview">
```

Is there a way to only find the exact match instead of finding all classes that somehow contain the said class name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should have a look at this issue: [BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): finding exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match)

The answer seems to be :

```
descContainer = descContainers[0].find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and 
                               tag.get('class') == ['userHtml'])
```

Answer (score 4):

What about a more concise and readable [CSS selector](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
descContainers[0].select("div[class=userHtml]")
```