# When using the .findAll() method, Beautifulsoup is counting too many tags

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm in the process of writing code for webscraping, and it seems like the .findAll() function in beautifulsoup merely finds the tags whose class attributes contain the specified class name.

For example, if I write `container = page_soup.findAll('div',{'class':'compare-collapse'})`, `container` will contain div tags whose classes are not only `'compare-collapse'`, but also `'compare-collapse compare-collapse_collapsed'`. I only want to find div tags whose class attributes are *only* `'compare-collapse'`. I've used Beautifulsoup before, and I didn't encounter this problem.

Here's my code. I wrote my code with many containers to make it easier to debug. The bug happens at container3.

```
html = driver.page_source
page_soup = soup(html,"html.parser")

container1=page_soup

container2=container1.findAll('div',{'id':'ratings'})
container2=container2[0]

container3=container2.findAll('div',{'class':'compare-collapse'}) #BUG HAPPENS HERE
container3=container3[1]

container4=container3.findAll('div',{'class':'compare-collapse_items'})
container4=container4[0]

container5=container4.findAll('div',{'class':'compare-section'})
container5=container5[0]

container6=container5.findAll('div',{'class':'container-fluid compare-row'})
container6=container6[2]

container7=container6.findAll('div',{'class':'row'})
container7=container7[0]

name=container7.div.div.text
print(name)
```

I previously stored all the containers in a text document.  `container3`'s class is `compare-collapse compare-collapse_collapsed`, instead of `compare-collapse`. How do I fix this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BeautifulSoup webscraping find\_all( ): finding exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match)

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate Of: 
[BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): finding exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match)

Please See From the above question.

base on your, it would be:

```
container = page_soup.findAll(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and 
                               tag.get('class') == ['compare-collapse'])
```