# how to select a tag with using binary logic?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a structure like this: (not is this particular order)

```
...
<div class="class1 class2">whatever</div>
<div class="class1">whatever</div>
<div class="class1">whatever</div>
<div class="class1 class2">whatever</div>
...
```

How to get/find only the "div" tags with class="class1" but not class="class1 class2"

Currently, I am using find_all to get a list of "div" with class_="class1" (including the undesirable "class2") and another list of class_="class2" and them, the difference. But this is so dumb and I am sure someone clever than me can get it done using the proper find argument in BS4.

I appreciate any comments and ideas. 
best regards,

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match

Answer (score 1):

This simple code should do it

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "www.website.com/page.html"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
tags = soup.select('div#class1')
```

Hope it helps !