# Beautifulsoup find_all() captures too much text

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML I am parsing in Python using the BeautifulSoup package. Here's the HTML:

```html
<div class='n'>Name</div>
<div class='x'>Address</div>
<div class='x'>Phone</div>
<div class='x c'>Other</div>
```

I am capturing the results using this code chunk:

```html
names = soup3.find_all('div', {'class': "n"}) 
contact = soup3.find_all('div', {'class': "x"})  
other = soup3.find_all('div', {'class': "x c"})
```

Right now, both classes 'x' and 'x c' are being captured in the 'contact' variable. How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: `class` `x` is presented 3 times on `Address` and `Phone` and `Other`, why you just not pickup by position ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
soup.select('div[class="x"]')
```

Output:

```
[<div class="x">Address</div>, <div class="x">Phone</div>]
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class='n'>Name</div>
<div class='x'>Address</div>
<div class='x'>Phone</div>
<div class='x c'>Other</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

contact = soup.findAll("div", class_="x")[1]

print(contact)
```

Output:

```
<div class="x">Phone</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using sets?

```
others = set(soup.find_all('div', {'class': "x c"}))
contacts = set(soup.find_all('div', {'class': "x"})) - others
```

**others** will be `{<div class="x c">Other</div>}`
and
**contacts** will be `{<div class="x">Phone</div>, <div class="x">Address</div>}`

Noted that this will only work in this specific case of classes. It may not work in general, depends on the combinations of classes you have in the HTML.

See [BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): finding exact match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match) for more details on how `.find_all()` works.