# BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): custom function not working

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So i'm scraping MCQs from this site. I want correct option at last. All options share same **class='radio-button-click-target'**. but the correct option has radio-button-click-target **correctquestions** at the end. I tried [BeautifulSoup webscraping find_all( ): finding exact match solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match) of [custom function](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function) but now none of the options are appearing.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
address = 'https://www.ilmkidunya.com/online-test/5th-class-science-english-meduim-mcqs-with-answers?startfrom=0&last=92'
response = requests.get(address)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
ques_id = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-title')
ques_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='q-desc')
optn_det = soup.find_all('div', class_='choose-answer-block')
for i in range(0, len(ques_id)):
    print((ques_id[i].text))
    print(str(ques_det[i].text).strip())
    options = optn_det[i].find_all(lambda tag: tag.name == 'div' and tag.get('class') == ['radio-button-click-target correctquestions'])
    for opn in options:
        print(str(opn.text).strip())
    print('<----->')
```

**CURRENT OUTPUT**

```
Question #  1
The group which belong to invertebrates is.
amphibians
Worms
Reptiles
Mammals
<----->
Question #  2
The main cause of cholera is:
land polllution
noise pollution
air pollution
water pollution
<----->
```

**Expected OUTPUT**

```
Question #  1
The group which belong to invertebrates is.
amphibians
Reptiles
Mammals
Worms
<----->
Question #  2
The main cause of cholera is:
land polllution
noise pollution
air pollution
water pollution
<----->
```

**Correct Option should be displayed at the end**

Comment: Please provide an example of expected output and actual output.

Comment: You can check it out now

Answer (score 6):

Everything you need is in the `HTML` so you can rebuild the trivia database by getting all the questions, suggested answers, and the correct answer.

Here's how:

```
import random
import time

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

address = 'https://www.ilmkidunya.com/online-test/5th-class-science-english-meduim-mcqs-with-answers?startfrom=0&last=92'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(address).text, 'lxml')

question = [
    q.getText(strip=True) for q
    in soup.select("div.single-question-answer-block div.q-desc")
]

radio_buttons = [
    o.getText(strip=True) for o in
    soup.select("div.fancy-radio-box .radio-button:disabled + .radio-button-click-target")
]

correct_answers = [
    a.getText(strip=True) for a in
    soup.find_all(lambda t: t.name == "label" and "correctquestions" in t["class"])
]

options = [radio_buttons[i:i + 4] for i in range(0, len(radio_buttons), 4)]

trivia_base = list(zip(question, correct_answers, options))

question, correct_answer, answers = random.choice(trivia_base)
time_to_answer_in_seconds = 15

print(question.title())
print("\n".join(f"-> {a.title()}" for a in answers))
print("-" * len(question))

time.sleep(time_to_answer_in_seconds)
print(f"Correct answer is: {correct_answer}.")
```

Sample output:

```
Which Of The Following Objects Emits Light?
-> Earth
-> Sun
-> Moon
-> Pluto
-------------------------------------------
Correct answer is: Sun.
```

EDIT:

If you want to print all the questions at once, use this:

```
trivia_base = list(zip(question, correct_answers, options))
horizontal_line = max(len(q) for q in question)

for number, trivia in enumerate(trivia_base, start=1):
    question, correct_answer, answers = trivia
    print(f"{number}. {question.title()}")
    print("\n".join(f"-> {a.title()}" for a in answers))
    print(f"Correct answer is: {correct_answer}.")
    print("-" * horizontal_line)
```

Output:

```
1. Which Of The Following Objects Emits Light?
-> Earth
-> Sun
-> Moon
-> Pluto
Correct answer is: Sun.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2. The Group Which Belongs To Invertebrates Is:
-> Amphibians
-> Insects
-> Reptiles
-> Birds
Correct answer is: insects.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3. Number Of Petals In A Flower Of Dicot Plant May Be:
-> 3
-> 4
-> 6
-> 7
Correct answer is: 4.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

and more...
```

Comment: I going to write this in a file. Is there anyway it can tell python to search the above four line and if any thing matched with the correct option line delete it. That way I can format them as I wanted