# How to find a specific HTML element using BeautifulSoup in Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have a website that I am trying to obtain a particular element from HTML using the requests and BeautifulSoup libraries but am struggling to get a match.

The code is as such:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://seekingalpha.com/symbol/AAPL/transcripts'

content = requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
```

From the Soup object I am trying to obtain this particular tag `<div data-test-id="post-list">` and have tried:

```
soup.find_all('<div data-test-id="post-list">')
```

However this returns an empty list `[]`. Is someone able to help me.

Thanks

Comment: Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match) Hope it helps.

Comment: In the source code, there are no `<div>`s with `data-test-id` attribute (you can check it in the broser - click `Ctrl`+`U`). What information are you trying to get?

Comment: When using the `find_all` function, you should just use the element type. For example: `soup.find_all('div')`. When I try this, there is a div that shows: `<div class="noScriptTitle">Javascript is Disabled</div>`. You'll need a way to execute Javascript to build the HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see on the page are loaded from external source. (In the source code, there are no `<div>`s with data-test-id attribute (you can check it in the browser - click `Ctrl`+`U` and search for the `data-test-id`).

To load the data from external source, try:

```py
import json
import requests

api_url = "https://seekingalpha.com/api/v3/symbols/aapl/transcripts"
params = {
    "filter[until]": "undefined",
    "id": "aapl",
    "include": "author,primaryTickers,secondaryTickers,sentiments",
    "isMounting": "true",
    "page[size]": "20",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

# pretty print the data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data["data"]:
    print(
        "{:<50}  {}".format(d["attributes"]["title"][:50], d["links"]["self"])
    )
```

Prints:

```
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q3 2021 Results   /article/4441901-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q3-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q2 2021 Results   /article/4422230-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q2-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q1 2021 Results   /article/4401478-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q1-2021-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q4 2020 Results   /article/4382943-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q4-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q3 2020 Results   /article/4362707-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q3-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q2 2020 Results   /article/4341792-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q2-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q1 2020 Results   /article/4319666-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q1-2020-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q4 2019 Results   /article/4300690-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q4-2019-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple, Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook On Q3 2019 Results  /article/4279301-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q3-2019-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple, Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q2 2019 Results  /article/4258275-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q2-2019-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple Inc. (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook on Q1 2019 Results   /article/4236503-apple-inc-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q1-2019-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q4 2018 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4217359-apple-aapl-q4-2018-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q3 2018 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4192790-apple-aapl-q3-2018-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q2 2018 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4168271-apple-aapl-q2-2018-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple's (AAPL) CEO Tim Cook On Q1 2018 Results - E  /article/4142447-apples-aapl-ceo-tim-cook-on-q1-2018-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q4 2017 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4119877-apple-aapl-q4-2017-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q3 2017 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4093437-apple-aapl-q3-2017-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q2 2017 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4068153-apple-aapl-q2-2017-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q1 2017 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4041266-apple-aapl-q1-2017-results-earnings-call-transcript
Apple (AAPL) Q4 2016 Results - Earnings Call Trans  /article/4014922-apple-aapl-q4-2016-results-earnings-call-transcript
```

Comment: Thanks, this is extremely helpful. The only problem is that I was working my way down as each one of those articles elements has an `href` to another webpage I need. Am I able to get that from this solution? Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Another question I have due to interest is how did you manage to find the `api_url`? I can't seem to find it on the source page

Comment: @geds133 If I understand you correctly, you can visit each link separately and get infromation from there (the link is in `d["links"]["self"]` in my example).

I found the API URL in Firefox Developer Tools->Network Tab

Comment: Thanks so much, this is exactly what I need. Appreciate the help

Comment: Hi, Just in the interest of learning, I had a couple of questions. Firstly, I am just wondering how the params were defined. Secondly in the print statement, I was wondering what this does in the string `{:<50}`. Thanks again

Comment: @geds133 I got the params inspecting how the request is made in the Network Tab. The `{:<50}` part is just string formatting, it means print string 50 characters wide aligned to the left.