# Beautifulsoup: find_all returns empty list and needs an exact matching string

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to learn webscraping in python. I followed Tim's tutorial until I got to a problem on minute 13:
[Youtube] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gRLHr664tXA&ab_channel=TechWithTim)

You can copy-paste the code to check out the problem. I used a small merch website since Amazon blocked access.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


#Add amazon site to access prices
URL = "https://do-something.de/products/just-do-something-t-shirt"

#get HTML file from URL
Web_Data = requests.get(URL)

#Parse (make correct syntax for the)document
HTML_File = BeautifulSoup(Web_Data.text, "html.parser")  

#Make a variable for finding all requested strings

###PROBLEM: I want to find the substring, not the exact string, 
# which is in this case "25,00€". I only want it to check the "€" sign
prices = BeautifulSoup.find_all(HTML_File, text='€') 

#Print file
print(prices)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

#Add amazon site to access prices
URL = "https://do-something.de/products/just-do-something-t-shirt"

#get HTML file from URL
Web_Data = requests.get(URL)

#Parse (make correct syntax for the)document
HTML_File = BeautifulSoup(Web_Data.text, "html.parser")  

#Make a variable for finding all requested strings

###PROBLEM: I want to find the substring, not the exact string, 
# which is in this case "25,00€". I only want it to check the "€" sign
# prices = BeautifulSoup.find_all(HTML_File, text='€') ## replace with 
prices = HTML_File.find_all(string= re.compile("€"))
for price in prices:
    print(price.text.strip())
    print('___________')
```

THis returns:

```
___________

___________
100,00€
___________

___________
25,00€
___________
Kostenloser Versand ab 100€ Bestellwert
___________
XXS - 25,00€
___________
XS - 25,00€
___________
S - 25,00€
___________
M - 25,00€
___________
L - 25,00€
___________
XL - 25,00€
___________
XXL - 25,00€
___________
XXXL - 25,00€
___________
Standardversand: 4,90€
___________
Kostenloser Versand ab einem Bestellwert von 100€
___________
13,00€
___________
16,50€
___________
12,00€
___________
16,00€
___________
14,00€
___________
18,00€
___________
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22726860/beautifulsoup-webscraping-find-all-finding-exact-match), relatively close.

Here's a working example for your context:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

text = """
<body>
    <div class="product">10€</div>
    <div class="product">1€</div>
    <div class="product special">2.4 €</div>
</body>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
result = soup.findAll(text=re.compile(r"\d+(,\d+)? ?€"))
print(result)
```

I hope it helps, the difference is quite small, I just replaced your
`'€'`
by
`re.compile(r"\d+(,\d+)? ?€")`

Answer (score 0):

One solution can be using custom `lambda` function that checks if strings ends with `€`:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = "https://do-something.de/products/just-do-something-t-shirt"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(URL).content, "html.parser")

product_meta = soup.find(class_="ProductMeta")

prices = product_meta.find_all(text=lambda t: t.endswith("€"))
print(prices)
```

Prints:

```
['25,00€']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. The string doesn't have to end with "€", it only has to contain it, but that's also another way to check it.